# How to read headers from web proxy with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

my angular app is called by an authenticating web-proxy that basically ensures user has signed-in on SSO. Web proxy calls my app with some headers that I want to read. Is there a way to do it with Angular 5?

with RoR it can be done something like

```
 email_address: request.env['HTTP_X_EMAIL'],
 first_name: request.env['HTTP_X_FIRSTNAME'],
 last_name: request.env['HTTP_X_LASTNAME']
```

I want read / access the headers passed by web-proxy. 
Just to clarify angular app is not calling the web proxy. Web proxy calls angular app.

Comment: i dont understand question. you want to set header of request (like basic authentication) or just some data in post request ?

Comment: I want read / access the headers passed by web-proxy. Just to clarify angular app is not calling the web proxy. Web proxy calls angular app